# i'm worked on augment app when i augmented the texture getting disordered

Tags: texturing

I'm working on an augmentation app.

I created an object, uv mapped and applied material (lambert). After that the baking process,saved the images that I baked and applied textured in gimp.

Applied textured image to the object and when i rendered in blender the textured topology is good, but in app when i'm rendering texture is getting distorted.

I don't understand where I made mistakes please suggest to me correct procedure. i exported my object to .obj format.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange.  Can you provide some screenshots.  Details re "the app".

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
 "Apply rotation and scale" before exporting, if it doesn't work try reimporting the .obj in Blender and analize what happened. If you still can't figure out, upload your file.